# Imageview visible for 3 seconds after app launch

Tags: android, webview, imageview

I am making an app with a webview. This webview uses some time by loading the url so I want a Imageview to be shown for about 3 seconds before it disappears. This is my layout file. How can i swap the visibility on these two views after 3 seconds have gone after app launch?

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageLoading1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />

<android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvwMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >
```

Comment: why dont you just use asynctask it was built for this type of scenarios in mind. Plus

Comment: @IllegalArgument asynctask was built for long-running background jobs. This is an ill fit for it.

Comment: @Hober what you are refering to is a service see the docs here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html read this line *for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)* in docs. Another reason I suggested async task is because if the loading finishes in 2 sec user can use app faster but if takes more than 3 then they keep seeing image unlike handler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.wvwMain).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 3000);
```

This will wait 3 seconds in the background, and after that it changes back to the UI thread and sets the visibilities.

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){ imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
},3000);
```

Comment: And if you set `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on the ViewGroup (such as LinearLayout or FrameLayout) that contains both, it'll even fade/animate the imageview away.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a Sample that how you can works with a CountDown.

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;   


public class Sample extends Activity {

  MyCustomCountDown timer;
  ImageView imageview;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1);
    timer = new MyCustomCountDown(3 * 1000, 1000);
    timer.start();
  }

  public class MyCustomCountDown extends CountDownTimer {
      public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
        //some script here
        imageview.setVisible(View.GONE); ////HERE HIDE YOUR IMAGE.
      }

      @Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //some script here 
      }   
    } 
}
```

Here is a [Sample to how make a Splash](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript:

```
myImageView.postDelayed(
new Runnable(){
public void run(){ 
myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
},3000);
```